# Add Azure Application Insights Status Monitor from command line

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/

I have a few sites hosted on a VM on azure that is deployed with Cloud Service Webroles.

Have anyone seen examples of installing the status monitor from code or command line? Goal is to add IIS sites automaticly to Azure App Insight without logging into remote desktop as shown in the link above.

Comment: We're working on this very same problem today... looking at using a combination of Startup Task in the csdef + Powershell & some custom chocolately/scripting to try and hack something together. though the 4th comment from Alan Willis doesn't fill me with hope. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/#comments

Comment: Ye, I cant figure out if one need to sign in in teh status monitor also or its enough to install it and then add the AI stuff to the website solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We ran into this issue also and wrote a script, which should plug into [the existing method for installing VS Online App Insights](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/16/new-agent-for-application-insights-available.aspx).

```csh
if(${env:InstalledStatusMonitor} -eq 1)
{
    Write-Host "Status monitor has already been installed on this machine by this script" -ForegroundColor Green
}

Write-Host "Using chocolatey to install the Web Platform Installer ..."  -ForegroundColor Green
iex ((new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
cinst webpi -y
Stop-Process -Name WebPlatformInstaller

Write-Host "Using Web Platform Installer to install Status Monitor ..." -ForegroundColor Green
&"$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd.exe" /Install /AcceptEula /Products:ApplicationInsightsStatusMonitor

Write-Host "Adding app pool account to the 'Performance Monitor Users' local group" -ForegroundColor Green
$group = "Performance Monitor Users"
$user = "Network Service"
$computer = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name
$de = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$group,group" 
$de.psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://$user").path)
Write-Host "Waiting 30 seconds for Status Monitor to finish its install ..." -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

Write-Host "Stop-Starting services to enable tracing..." -ForegroundColor Green
# For some reason, even though Status Monitor calls "iisreset.exe /restart"
# calling it here leaves IIS and website stopped.
&iisreset.exe /restart

Write-Host "waiting a few seconds..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
Write-Host "starting..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

Start-Service -Name W3SVC
Get-WebApplication | Select ApplicationPool -Unique | %{ Start-WebAppPool $_.applicationPool }
Get-Website | Start-Website
Write-Host "started" -ForegroundColor Yellow

Write-Host "Cleaning up running applications" -ForegroundColor Green
Stop-Process -Name Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor


Write-Host "Setting environment variable to indicate status monitor has been installed" -ForegroundColor Green
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("InstalledStatusMonitor", "1", "Machine")

Write-Host "Installation complete" -ForegroundColor Green
```

[I wrote a blog post about it here](http://www.greenfinch.ie/how-to-deploy-application-insights-status-monitor-preview-on-a-cloud-service-webrole/), so if we run into issues and I forget to update this post you should be able to see updates there.

## Update 1

Thanks to pksorensen for the direct link, it looks like this is where the Web Platform installer downloads the package from. I've done some more with this and now have a fully automated process working. [I have a sample repository available here with a working project.](https://github.com/greenfinch/sample-net-AzureApplicationInsightsStatusMonitor). [This commit should describe what you need to do to your own web project to get Status Monitor working on a Web Role.](https://github.com/greenfinch/sample-net-AzureApplicationInsightsStatusMonitor/commit/4a6a47dd5cfdceaf18ce2126240b2d8ec5184042)

[There is a post by Sergey Kanzhelev](http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/03/05/status-monitor-for-cloud-services/), indicating that it should be possible to do this to worker roles too.

Here are the individual steps required. I will try to provide an update on non-web roles if I get a chance to look into it:

#### 1. ServiceDefinition.csdef

Add the following Startup entry into your web deployment project, it will run when the role is being created or deployed to.

```xml
<ServiceDefinition>
  <WebRole>

    ...

    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="Role_Start\Bootstrap.bat" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
        <Environment>
          <Variable name="EMULATED">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
          </Variable>
        </Environment>
      </Task>
    </Startup>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

#### 2. WebProject/Role_Start/Bootstrap.bat

This is the batch file called by the startup task. It has to be placed in your web project. Set the properties to always copy the file to output directory.

```
:: The basis for this script is described here
:: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/16/new-agent-for-application-insights-available.aspx
:: The scripts can be downloaded directly from
:: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=329971

@echo off

:: Do not attempt to install the agent on an emulated environment
if "%EMULATED%"=="true" goto :EndOfScript

:: Set appropriate execution policy on the host machine
set ExecutionPolicyLevel=RemoteSigned
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`powershell -noprofile -command "Get-ExecutionPolicy"`) do (
    set ExecutionPolicy=%%i
    if /I "%%i"=="Unrestricted" goto :AllIsWell
    if /I "%%i"=="RemoteSigned" goto :AllIsWell
    Powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" < NUL >> NUL 2>> NUL
)

:AllIsWell

Powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& '%~dp0InstallStatusMonitor.ps1'" < NUL  >> NUL 2>> NUL
echo "done" >"%ROLEROOT%\startup.task.done.sem"

:EndOfScript

exit 0
```

#### 3. WebProject/Role_Start/InstallStatusMonitor.ps1

Like the Bootstrap.bat file, set the properties to copy this file to the output directory also. This is an updated version of the script posted earlier

```csh
# The basis for this script is described here
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/16/new-agent-for-application-insights-available.aspx
# The scripts can be downloaded directly from
# http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=329971

#Constants
$downloadUrl = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=512247&clcid=0x409"

# Variables
$rootDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$downloadPath = Join-Path $rootDir "ApplicationInsightsAgent.msi"

# Functions
# Infrastructure functions
function TryV1
{
    param
    (
        [ScriptBlock] $Command = $(throw "The parameter -Command is required."),
        [ScriptBlock] $Catch   = { throw $_ },
        [ScriptBlock] $Finally = { }
    )

    & {
        $local:ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

        trap
        {
            trap
            {
                & {
                    trap { throw $_ }
                    & $Finally
                }

                throw $_
            }

            $_ | & { & $Catch }
        }

        & $Command
    }

    & {
        trap { throw $_ }
        & $Finally
    }
}

function Retry
{
    param (
        [ScriptBlock] $RetryCommand
    )

    for ($attempts=0; $attempts -lt 5; $attempts++)
    {        
        TryV1 {

            & $RetryCommand
            break

        } -Catch {

            if($attempts -lt 4)
            {
                Log-Message "Attempt:$attempts Exception Occured. Sleeping and Retrying..."
                Log-Message $_
                Log-Message $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            }
            else
            {
                throw $_
            }
        }
    }

}

function Log-Message
{
    param(
        [string] $message
    )

    $logString = ("{0}: {1}" -f (Get-Date), $message)
    $unifiedStartupInfoLogPath = Join-Path $rootDir "ApmAgentInstall.log"
    Add-Content $unifiedStartupInfoLogPath $logString
    Write-Host $logString -ForegroundColor Green
}

function Log-Error
{
    param(
        [string] $message
    )
    $logString =  ("{0}: {1}" -f (Get-Date), $message)
    $unifiedStartupErrorLogPath = Join-Path $rootDir "ApmAgentInstallError.log"
    Add-Content $unifiedStartupInfoLogPath $logString
    Write-Host $logString -ForegroundColor Red
}

# Functions
# Operations functions
function Get-AppInsightsInstallationStatus(){

    if(${env:InstalledStatusMonitor} -eq 1)
    {
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        return $false
    }
}

function Download-StatusMonitor
{
    Retry {

        $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
        $wc.DownloadFile($downloadUrl, $downloadPath)
    }
}

function Install-StatusMonitor(){
    $logPath = Join-Path $rootDir "StatusMonitorInstall.log"
    &$downloadPath /quiet /passive /log $logPath
    Log-Message "Waiting 30 seconds for Status Monitor to finish its install ..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}

function Grant-LoggingPermissionToAppPool(){
    $groupName = "Performance Monitor Users"
    $user = "Network Service"
    $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://./$groupName,group"
    if(($group.PSBase.Invoke('Members') | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -contains $user)
    {
        Log-Message "'$user' is already a member of '$groupName', don't need to do anything"
        return
    }    
    else
    {
        Log-Message "'$user' is now a member of '$groupName'"
        $group.Add("WinNT://$user")
    }
}

function Restart-IISOnAzureWebRole(){
    # For some reason, even though Status Monitor calls "iisreset.exe /restart"
    # calling it here leaves IIS and website stopped.
    &iisreset.exe /restart

    Log-Message "waiting a few seconds..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    Log-Message "starting..."

    Start-Service -Name W3SVC
    Get-WebApplication | Select ApplicationPool -Unique | %{ Start-WebAppPool $_.applicationPool }
    Get-Website | Start-Website
    Log-Message "started"
}

# Main body
Log-Message "Starting Status Monitor installation"

Log-Message "Downloading component..."
Download-StatusMonitor

Log-Message "Installing component..."
Install-StatusMonitor

Log-Message "Adding app pool account to the 'Performance Monitor Users' local group"
Grant-LoggingPermissionToAppPool

Log-Message "Stop-Starting services to enable tracing..."
Restart-IISOnAzureWebRole

Log-Message "Completed installation successfully"
```

## Update 2

If you need the capability to add custom properties to track on, such as being able to discriminate dependencies based on role names or role instances you need to get into the Application Insights pipleline earlier than is described in the documentation.

Let's say you want to be able to filter on Role Name and Role Instance Id,  you would create a custom context initializer.

```csh
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

namespace Utilities
{
    public class AppInsightsCurrentRoleIdAsTagInitializer : Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.IContextInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(TelemetryContext context)
        {
            context.Properties["Greenfinch - RoleName"] = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name;
            context.Properties["Greenfinch - RoleInstanceId"] = InstanceId;
        }

        private string InstanceId
        {
            get
            {
                var instanceId = Regex.Match(RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id, "\\d+$", RegexOptions.Compiled).Value;
                return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(instanceId)
                    ? "unable to get instance id"
                    : instanceId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but instead of plugging it in in code, you would instead add it to the ApplicationInsights.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" schemaVersion="2014-05-30">

  ...

  <ContextInitializers>

    ...

    <Add Type="Utilities.AppInsightsCurrentRoleIdAsTagInitializer, Utilities" />
  </ContextInitializers>

  ...

</ApplicationInsights>
```

Comment: So signing in after installing status monitor is not needed? It just need to be installed?

Comment: No, absolutely not. This tool gives you the ability to add App Insights to applications that are already installed, which would require you to log in. If you want to go with a quick and dirty option you can install it and reboot the whole machine. The components will work after that.

Comment: Cool. I had App Insights added to the websites already. Will just add the bits to install status monitor. For others, heres the direct link to MSI without platform installer: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=512247&clcid=0x409

Comment: pksorensen, that's a link to the Visual Studio Online version. Isn't that different than the one installed by the web platform installer? I'm pretty sure that I saw someone say that while it's still around, the VS Online version will work just as well as the new Status Monitor

Comment: I dont know. I got it from here: https://twitter.com/SergeyKanzhelev/status/572568462339358720

Comment: pksorensen, that link is actually correct. It is the very same link as appears in the XML feed for the web platform installer.

Comment: Now updated for a completely working solution without RDP. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Also, Sergey added a link to your post now. http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/03/05/status-monitor-for-cloud-services/

Comment: ahh ,you found the link your self. didnt notice the updates before posting the comment.

Comment: I installed it from c# instead of your ps script, but I am wondering if in your setup the status monitor starts itself? It didnt for my case

Comment: Nothing needs to be running, the components hook into IIS. You will, however, need to reset the entire IIS pipeline after installing, in order to get them to work.

Comment: Added information on how to get custom properties working when tracking dependencies

Comment: Not sure if you seen, these are also as properties on context.  https://gist.github.com/s093294/4bffe208477918088a8f

Comment: I did see these properties, however, they were not being populated when I was doing my testing. Did you have better luck with this?

Comment: There is this one that should populate them:     <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.AzureRoleEnvironmentContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />  But i didnt bring in the .Web dll in my worker role, so I am setting it my self.

Comment: I had a look at these, and they are added automatically when you add the package. However, there are discrepancies in what is tagged by one vs the other. For worker roles, for example, the one I have does appear to work, while the built-in one does not.

Answer (score 0):

In my IAAS model, I referenced these [scripts](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/5f9cb502bf115777c1bbe4d6c3143901216a35cd/Samples/AzureEmailService/MvcWebRole/AppInsightsAgent) to set it up, it also uses the direct msi URL as opposed to Web Platform, before installation and restarts IIS.

I used PowerShell DSC for this and some sort of blue-green IIS resets so there are no outages, so servers could be configured with Status monitor as a part of initial provisioning and the application code could drive the telemetry.

```
Package AppInsights
     {                             

        Ensure      = "Present"  
        Path        = "E:\dsc\ApplicationInsightsAgent.msi" # copied at some vm location
        Name        = "Application Insights Status Monitor"
        ProductID   =  "CBF2C62C-9537-4D8E-9754-92E54A0822D4"                       
    }
```

If your web.config doesn't have the instrumentation key, you may use below to enable for your website in your DSC, post installation.

```
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Application Insights\Status Monitor\PowerShell\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.PowerShell.dll'
Start-ApplicationInsightsMonitoring -Name 'your web site' -InstrumentationKey '<KeyHere>'
```