# Setting up run-time Application Insights on a Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-insights

According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now), Application Insights is best deployed both at build time and run-time, and can be installed at run-time by "select[ing] Application Insights on the app's control panel in Azure". But I don't see it on the configuration for Cloud services, at least not in the new portal:

Is the documentation incorrect (necessitating the long process laid out [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28875031/1180926) still required)? If not, where should I be looking?

[image]

**EDIT 3** You can supposedly set it [while publishing from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-cloudservices#quick-start) (if you upgrade the Azure SDK to 2.9 and "Add Diagnostic Configuration" in Visual Studio for the project):
[image]

but it still insists I download the Status Monitor:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Portal, currently there is **no** Application InSights on the Cloud Service control panel. We could find the Application InSights on the **Azure App Service**.  Azure App Service and Cloud Service are different services in Azure.  The difference between Azure AppService and CloudService please refer to [Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm).

> "select[ing] Application Insights on the app's control panel in Azure"

In the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps) that you mentioned, it is for Azure App service

> Select Application Insights in the Azure control panel for your **web app**

[image]

For Cloud Service,  please refer to document, there are more detail steps  about [how to setup Application Insights for each role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-cloudservices#create-an-application-insights-resource-for-each-role) .

Comment: So the documentation is incorrect? It clearly says "If your app is an Azure web app or Cloud Service".

Comment: Also, that's for build-time monitoring. It doesn't help for the run-time SQL call monitoring (a comment someone asked on that document you said to refer to two days ago).

Comment: `If your app is an Azure web app or Cloud Service`, from my experenice, there is no Application Insights on the app's control panel in Azure currently. I will report it.

Comment: *that - the link "how to setup Application Insights for each role"